# Sage code for finding generator matrix of MDS code

Tags: implementation, number-theory, threshold-cryptography, mds, multivariate-cryptography

1. Let $L$ be an $[n,k]$ code. A $k\times n$ matrix $G$ whose rows form a basis for $L$ is called a **generator matrix** for $L$.
2. A linear $[n,k,d]$ code with largest possible minimum distance is called maximum distance $d$ separable or **MDS** code.

I want to find a generator matrix for MDS code using SageMath or in another way, is there any SageMath code to check a matrix is a generator matrix for the MDS code. Any help with the SageMath code for the generator matrix will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LinearCode` (with the generator matrix as the argument):

```
sage: C = LinearCode(random_matrix(GF(11), 3, 7))                                                                                                                                                                                              
sage: C.minimum_distance()                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
4
```

However, for general codes (e.g. random codes), finding the minimum distance (and checking if it's MDS) is a hard problem. Therefore, you can only do it for small matrices.

To generate an MDS matrix, you can use concrete constructions, such as the [Cauchy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix). The generator matrix of the associated linear code can be obtained by concatenating it with the identity matrix.

Comment: Could you provide a paper for the hardness of the problem?

Comment: @kelalaka See e.g. https://madhu.seas.harvard.edu/papers/1999/dms-journ.pdf , even approximating the minimum distance up to a constant factor is hard